# Draw a simple plotly line graph horizontally

Tags: javascript, plotly

With the bar graph, you can add `orientation: h` to the trace.

Couldn't find a way to do that with line graph, so a basic graph like this one:

[image]

Can be rotated to look something like this (rotated in gimp...):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there is no direct of doing so but you can take advantage of Plotly using D3 and the fact that all graphs are SVGs.

By applying [`rotate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform) and `transform` to the plot itself you get the desired result.

```
Plotly.d3.selectAll(".subplot").filter(".xy").attr('transform', 'rotate(90) translate(0, -400)');
```

The class of the plot is `"subplot xy"` and 400 is the width of your plot (specified in the HTML definition of your div).

---

If you want to rotate the whole graph use:

```
Plotly.d3.selectAll(".main-svg").attr('transform', 'rotate(90) translate(0, -400)');
```

Probably the legend needs to be adjusted a bit afterwards:

```
Plotly.d3.selectAll(".legend").attr('transform', 'translate(100, 50)');
```

I'd recommend [`disabling`](https://plot.ly/javascript/reference/#layout-hovermode) the hoverinfo or modify it as well.

```
var layout = {hovermode: false};
Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
```

```js
var trace1 = {
  x: [1, 2, 3, 4],
  y: [10, 15, 13, 17],
  type: 'scatter'
};

var trace2 = {
  x: [1, 2, 3, 4],
  y: [16, 5, 11, 9],
  type: 'scatter'
};

var data = [trace1, trace2];
Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data);

//rotation happens here
Plotly.d3.selectAll(".subplot").filter(".xy").attr('transform', 'rotate(90) translate(0, -400)');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv" style="width: 400px; height: 400px;"></div>
```

---

Comment: This is awesome. Is there any way to rotate the legend labels as well so it will look perfect?